# EACCES: permission denied

Tags: node.js, reactjs

hi i just update node in my ec2 and i have this problem when i tried to build my react app i follow this tutorial https://guillermo.at/update-node-proper-way someone can help me?

`Updating 5aa9aef..83ab7d5 Fast-forward .gitlab-ci.yml | 2 +- 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-) up to date, audited 2247 packages in 7s 224 packages are looking for funding run npm fund for details 36 vulnerabilities (2 low, 5 moderate, 26 high, 3 critical) To address issues that do not require attention, run: npm audit fix To address all issues (including breaking changes), run: npm audit fix --force Run npm audit for details.`

> distrito-front@0.1.0 build
> env-cmd -f .env.development react-scripts build
> Failed to compile.
> EACCES: permission denied, unlink '/home/ubuntu/dev/distrito-front/build/dp_colores.svg'`

i run `ls -l /home/ubuntu/dev/distrito-front/build/dp_colores.svg` `whoami`
this is the result

`-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 1584 Sep 23 18:25 /home/ubuntu/dev/distrito-front/build/dp_colores.svg`
`ubuntu`

Comment: You certainly trying removing a file named `/home/ubuntu/dev/distrito-front/build/dp_colores.svg` without having rigths to do this. Check this file permissions against the user you use to login.

Comment: sorry im super noob in this how i check that

Comment: Run these commands, and add result in you question:

`ls -l /home/ubuntu/dev/distrito-front/build/dp_colores.svg`

`whoami`

Comment: sorry i wrote the wrong asnwer `-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 1584 Sep 23 18:25 /home/ubuntu/dev/distrito-front/build/dp_colores.svg` `ubuntu`

Comment: So it is normal.
Your file is owned by root user and root group. As you are login with ubuntu user and others permission is only read access, you can't delete that file.

Comment: ok ok i get it so how i change to root or in that case add ubuntu to root group

Comment: Not the good question i think. The good question is why this file, and perharps some others, are owned by root instead of ubuntu.
The best is to add `sudo` before your command

Comment: maybe i mess up when update node i dont kwon